# Problem in Apache installation

Tags: apache2, lamp, apache2.4

Before Apache worked normally, but after uninstall and install I have this.

[image]

Comment: The screenshot - which you should have copied and pasted here, with `code` formatting, instead of uploading as a picture - points at at least three sources of more information. There is `systemctl status apache2.service`; there is `journalctl -xe`; and there is the Apache2 error log, which is located at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`. What can you tell from these logs? The "Could not reliably determine..." message at the bottom here is just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The errer states that port 80 is already in use...

If you did not start another service on that port, you probably have two Listen directives in your configfiles.